# remove leading zeros (optional) from regex, with max length

Tags: regex

I have a validation regex, that checks that the user sent a query param in this format-
an integer with max length of 10 - meaning it can be an integer between 0 and 10, and it can also contain **leading** zeros (any number of zeros at the beginning), but its **optional**.

Examples:

| String | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | valid |
| 000001234567890 | valid |
| 012345678900 | not valid |
| 12345678901 | not valid |
| 000000000012547 | valid |

this is my regex, but it doesn't seem to work

```
"^(0+)?|[0-9]{0,10}+$"
```

**`^(0+)?`** - this is suppose to be the optional leading zeros at the beginning

**`[0-9]{0,10}+`** - this is suppose to be the integer with the length validation

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^0*[1-9]\d{0,9}$
^0*[1-9][0-9]{0,9}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PEna9c/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `0*` - zero or more leading zeros
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `[0-9]{0,9}` - zero to nine digits
- `$` - end of string.

If you allow an empty string, you can use

```
^(?:0*[1-9][0-9]{0,9})?$
```

where the pattern between anchors is optional.

Comment: Just FYI: if a `0` number is allowed, too, then you might want to match zero to ten `0`s: `^(?:0*[1-9]\d{0,9}|0{0,10})$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PEna9c/2)).

Comment: PERFECT!
thank you!!